# ember.js components properties errors out with " TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'isEditing' in undefined"

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a fairly standard ember.js component:

```
{{#wiki/wiki-field isEditing=isEditing fieldText=summary maxLength=2800}}                  
  Summary
{{/wiki/wiki-field}}
```

It's error'ing out:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'isEditing' in undefined

It appears that this is erroring out searching for `isEditing` among the view keywords:(This is the line from ember.debug.js)

```
} else if (key in this.view._keywords) {
```

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly special about this, which is why I'm miffed that I can't find anything about it.  I'm using ember-cli, configuring my modules in pods.

The component is stored in:

- components/wiki/wiki-field/template.hbs
- components/wiki/wiki-field/component.coffee

Answer (score 10):

Do you happen to be calling init like below?

```
 export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init: function(){
    //do stuff here...
  },
```

If so, make sure you are calling  this._super(); at some point in time within your init call.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
 init: function(){
    //do stuff here..
    this._super();
    //do stuff here...
 },
```

If that is not the case, please post your code.